# "Object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE11

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

I am getting the error

> Critical Error: Object doesn't support this property or method addeventlistener

while accessing the InfoPath form page (using InfoPath enabled list form e.g. displayifs.aspx) in IE 11 browser.

This error is specific to IE 11, the page is opening properly in IE 10 and below. According to [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IE 11 supports addEventListener.

Anybody have an idea on this?

Answer (score 31):

This unfortunately breaks other things. Here is the fix I found on another [site](http://www.markadrake.com/blog/2013/12/13/sharepoint-workflows-fail-using-ie11/) that seemed to work for me:

I'd say leave the `X-UA-Compatible` as `"IE=8"` and  add the following code to the bottom of your master page:

```
<script language="javascript">
    /* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
    if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
    {
        UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
    } 
</script>
```

This fixes a bug in `core.js` which incorrectly calculates that sets `UserAgentInfo.strBrowse=3` for IE11 and thus supporting `addEventListener`.  I'm not entirely sure on the details other than that but the combination of keeping IE=8 and using this script is working for me. Fingers crossed until I find the next IE11/SharePoint "bug"!

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Especially because of the bad information from Chris R and JoshC below. You should not change the X-UA-Compatible tag to anything other than IE8 when using SharePoint 2010. This only concerns people who are using the SharePoint Web UI to edit and maintain the site. If you are running an internet site, it's 99% safe to serve a different x-ua tag for anonymous users. Read this for info on how to. http://francoisverbeeck.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/sharepoint-tip-of-the-day-x-ua-compatible-ie/

Comment: Issue with upgrade-migrated sites from 2007 to 2010; sites were still using default.master page with UI version compatibility set to 3. Setting default to v4.master and adding the above script resolved the issue with InfoPath forms.

Comment: @user3116631 Hi guysI have been trying to solve this issue for weeks, I added above code to the v4.master page but it didn't work, how to set default to v4.master ?

thanks

Comment: and is this the right place to add it ?

 <script language="javascript">
    /* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
    if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
    {
        UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
    } 
</script> 
</body>

Answer (score 23):

Best way to solve this until a fix is available (if a fix comes) is to force IE compatibility mode on the user.

Use `<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` ideally in the masterpage so all pages in your site get the workaround.

Comment: This works, just tested with IE11, I added it to the _Layout.cshtml page

Comment: worked well with my wordpress site, thanks. added the meta tag in the header.php

Answer (score 5):

We were also facing this issue when using IE version 11 to access our **React** app (create-react-app with react version 16.0.0 with jQuery v3.1.1) on the enterprise intranet. To solve it, i simply followed the directions at this [url](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-2-1-1-min-js-object-doesn-t-support-property-or-method-addeventlistener) which are also listed below:

1. Make sure to set the DOCTYPE to standards mode by making sure the first line of the master file is: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Force IE 11 to use the latest internal version by including the following meta tag in the head tag:  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />`

NOTE: I did not face the problem when using IE to access the app in development mode on my local machine (localhost:3000). **The problem occurred only when accessing the app deployed to the DEV server on the company Intranet, probably because of some company wide Windows OS policy settings and/or IE Internet Options.**

Answer (score 2):

Add the code snippet in JS file used in master page or used globally.

```
<script language="javascript">
if (typeof browseris !== 'undefined') {
    browseris.ie = false;
}
</script>
```

For more information refer blog: http://blogs2share.blogspot.in/2016/11/object-doesnt-support-property-or.html

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this for me was that I had a React component being rendered prior to my core.js shim being loaded.

```
import ReactComponent from '.'
import 'core-js/es6'
```

Loading the core-js prior to the ReactComponent fixed my issue

```
import 'core-js/es6'
import ReactComponent from '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the similar issue and surprisingly meta tag didn't work this time.
Turns out the company I currently cooperate with has this [enterprise mode setting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2015/04/11/ie-enterprise-mode-in-a-nutshell/) which has priority over meta tag.

We can't change the setting cause policy issue. Luckily I don't really need any fancy features but basic usage of jQuery so my final solution is to switch its version to 1.12 for better compatibility.

ref: [jQuery - Browser support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Answer (score 0):

We have set compatibility mode for IE11 to resolve an issue: Settings>Compatibility View Settings>Add your site name or Check "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" if your portal is in the intranet.

IE version 11.0.9600.16521

Worked for us, hope this helps someone.