# Critical Error: Object doesn't support this property or method addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010

actually I have a really weird problem, that I have been trying to solve for two weeks.

to begin with, I am using sharePoint 2010. we created **two** dashboards that fetch information from lists and then display them in a graphical form, simply the javaScript script using AJAX get the list and then use the information. its worth mentioning that I am using Jquery

here is a picture of what I am talking about:
[image]

lets say this is **dashboard1**

is working like a charm in all browser even internet explorer

the problem is with another dashboard, **dashboard2**,

the problem with **dashboard2** is that, a jquery problem as I copied from the console:

> Critical Error: Object doesn't support this property or method addeventlistener

to get what I mean, the navigation bars on the right get its html from the list that I fetch and I use jquery and bootstrab for collapse , this is how the not working page looks like:

[image]

the navigation bar doesn't get its items, the graphs don't load
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829292/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-in-ie11) fix but it didn't work.

what I suspected is that, this problem is related to sharePoint somehow,let me tell you what else I have tried, I made another copy of the index.html which is the main index page for **dashboard1** the working dashboard, and I called it test.html which has exactly the same code, its supposed to work right ? because this is just a copy of the index.html that is working in internet explorer and all browsers, but surprisingly it didn't work and I got the same error that I got when I run the other index2.html the one for the other dashboard (dashboard2).

what can cause this problem? and fixes can I try? Its nothing related to the code ( I can share the code if you want) but its a bug related to sharepoint or Microsoft explorer or both !

> Critical Error: Object doesn't support this property or method addeventlistener

Comment: I don't know anything about SharePoint, but in JavaScript, `addeventlistener` is not a thing; `addEventListener` is. Are you *sure* your code is okay?

Comment: yes the code is working, this dashboard1 is also working in IE, but when I made another copy of the index.html page of dashboard1, it didn't work !

weirdness to its finest