# “Object doesn't support this property or method” error in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have encountered this error when using AWS S3 upload. I have searched for existing questions about this one and found this:

["Object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829292/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-in-ie11)

Similar MSDN page has also recommended this approach:

```
<script language="javascript">
    /* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
    if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
    {
        UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
    } 
</script>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me. UserAgentInfo is undefined for me.

[image]

And the IE version is IE11. How should I walk around this issue?

**Edit**

My code looks like below:

```
var params = {
    Key: 'content-upload-development/' + file.name,
    ContentType: file.type,
    Body: file
};
bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt){
    var percent = parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total);
    var signedFormData = null;
    $(document).trigger("AmazonStatusUpdateEvent", ["Uploading", file.name, percent, signedFormData]);
}).send(function(err, data) {
    var signedFormData = {};
    console.log(err);
    //signedFormData.fileURL = data.Location;
    signedFormData.fileSize = "400m";
    $( document ).trigger( "AmazonStatusUpdateEvent", [ "Completed", file.name, 100, signedFormData ] ); 
});
```

Please note the console.log(error) is the line which outputs the error message into the browser's console. I have no idea where addEventListener is called. Global searched that but didn't find anything related.

Comment: I don't see how a sharepoint question relates to your AWS issue. What **exactly** is the error message in **your code** referring to?

Comment: *Which* method does the object not support? Please post the complete error message.

Comment: See [*this post*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5a81a95b-a4d0-4e6c-a8c4-5602698e5a32/windows-81-and-ie11-critical-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-addeventlistener?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) in the Office dev centre.

Comment: @RobG That's about `addEventListener`, his error is for `UserAgentInfo`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not so sure about that. It appears OP has searched for "IE 11 Object doesn't support..." and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829292/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-in-ie11). It's not clear if that has anything to do with OP's actual issue

Comment: @RobG In fact, that page contains the above code as the recommended fix for the problem. It's in the 5th reply.

Comment: @Barmar My error is about addEventListener. I am getting exactly the same error as mentioned in the title

Comment: @LanceShi that might be your error message but what does your code look like?

Comment: @Phil I am getting the same error message as the one in sharepoint. Also the other post has stated this issue not only impacts sharepoint

Comment: @Phil included the code.

Comment: are you in IE8 or lower emulation mode in IE perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX Not really... I am pretty sure it is IE11

Comment: IE11 can emulate it's more retarded brothers

Comment: @JaromandaX I haven't turned on emulation mode though... Strange

Comment: I haven't figured out what the question is about to be honest ... all I know is that IE<9 does not have `addEventListener`